# full size sidebar without background image

Tags: html, css

My sidebar does not reach 100% of height:

http://jsfiddle.net/PnsDD/

I dont want to implement faux-columns technique since it needs a background image. And I cannot implement some idea using `display` since for having a sticky footer I have changed some displays to `table` or `table-row`.

any solution?

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">header header header header header</div>
    <div id="main">John Edward Brownlee was Premier of Alberta, Canada, from 1925 to 1934
        as leader of the United Farmers of Alberta (UFA) caucus. After winning
        the 1926 election, his successes included obtaining control of Alberta's
        natural resources from the federal government and selling the money-losing
        railways to help balance the provincial budget. His government's fortunes
        declined after the 1930 election. Agricultural prices collapsed, throwing
        many farmers into poverty. He tried to broker deals between farmers and
        banks, but found neither side eager to compromise. In 1933, Prime Minister
        R. B. Bennett named Brownlee to the Royal Commission on Banking and Currency
        as a representative of western interests and unorthodox viewpoints. While
        Brownlee concurred with the commission's ultimate recommendation for the
        creation of a central bank, he also made his own recommendations. In 1934
        he was sued for the seduction of Vivian MacMillan, a family friend and
        a secretary in his government's attorney-general's office, who claimed
        that they had carried on an affair for three years. The jury sided with
        MacMillan despite Brownlee's denials and, in deference to public outrage,
        he resigned as premier. (Full article...)</div>
    <div id="sidebar">sidebar sidebar sidebar sidebar sidebar sidebar sidebar sidebar sidebar
        sidebar sidebar sidebar sidebar sidebar sidebar sidebar sidebar sidebar
        sidebar sidebar</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer
    footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer
    footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer
    footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer
    footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer
    footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer
    footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer
    footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer
    footer footer</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {height: 100%;}

body
{
display: table;
}

#header,
#main,
#footer
{
    display: table-row;

}

#header,
#footer
{
    height: 1px;
width: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
    height: auto;
}

#wrapper
{
width:90%;
margin:0 auto;
background-color: #FFFFF0;
min-height: 100%;
display: table;
}

#main
{

width:75%;
float:left;
background-color: #FFF0FF;
}

#sidebar
{

width:25%;
float:right;
background-color: #F0FFFF;
}

#header
{
background-color: #FFDDFF;
}

#footer
{
background-color: #DDDDDD;
position:relative;
clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Give height to sidebar div.

Comment: giving height 100% does not work at all: http://jsfiddle.net/PnsDD/4/

Comment: not 100%.give in `px`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a wrapper to the #main and #sidebar and make it relative, then use absolute positioning on the sidebar to create a faux column.

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PnsDD/2/

Relevant code:

```
<div class="content-wrap">
    <div id="main"></div>
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content-wrap {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}

#sidebar {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    width:25%;
}
```

**EDIT**

However, based on the fiddle, you could honestly just give the wrapper the green background and let it appear as if the sidebar were just as high. I don't know if this would fit your actual need, though. See another fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PnsDD/12/

Comment: Thanks robooneus, your idea is great, however I faced with new problem when sidebar is longer than main content and it overflows. do you have any solution for that? http://jsfiddle.net/Dse8U/

Comment: @esrpim Hmm... will have to think about it. But my gut says that in using the method above, there is no way to ensure this dynamically. The simplest would be to just set a `min-height` on `#main` that is somewhat reasonable. But that could break if you have extremely long sidebar content. Otherwise you would need to set the min-height with JS on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can force the height of the sidebar to match the height of the floated div next to it. However, if you tweak your HMTL and make the container have the background you want then you can achieve something like what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/uJ5jh/

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="content">
    main content
  </div>
  sidebar
</div> 

#main
{
  background-color: #F0FFFF;     
}

#content
{
  width:75%;
  float:left;
  background-color: #FFF0FF; 
}
```